# Remove double quotes from the js array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, split

I have this type of array

```
[[["80.529299450867271,7.3884550841172976"],["80.528953669541707,7.3875715810979612"],["80.528714422417153,7.3867339810469588"]]]
```

I want to get this as

```
[[[80.529299450867271,7.3884550841172976],[80.528953669541707,7.3875715810979612],[80.528714422417153,7.3867339810469588]]]
```

this is what I have tried

```
z = a.map(function(o) {
  var d = o.split(/(],)/g).map(function(b) {
    console.log();
    return b;
});
```

Comment: Why don't you fix the source of the erroneous array instead?

Comment: Wait, if you're doing `o.split(/(],)/g)` then it doesn't seem you have an array but JSON. In that case as @Andreas said - correct the source of the data. It's always a bad idea to post-fix JSON after it's generated.

Answer (score 2):

[**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) might be used in that scenario. Make an iteration over the array and split the item.

After spiting I used another map to convert the string to number.

```js
const arr = [
    [
        [
            "80.529299450867271,7.3884550841172976"
        ],
        [
            "80.528953669541707,7.3875715810979612"
        ],
        [
            "80.528714422417153,7.3867339810469588"
        ]
    ]
]

const result = [arr[0].map(i => i[0].split(',').map(Number))]
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Answer:

You can map over the inner array and split the strings, then cast the members of the returned arrays to Numbers.

```
arr[0] = arr[0].map(([v]) => v.split(",").map(Number));
```

---

### Working Example:

```js
let arr = [[["80.529299450867271,7.3884550841172976"],["80.528953669541707,7.3875715810979612"],["80.528714422417153,7.3867339810469588"]]];

arr[0] = arr[0].map(([v]) => v.split(",").map(Number));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you for using the word "cast"!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove the quotes - it's not the problem. Try this (with **parseFloat()**):

```js
const arr = [
  [
    ["80.529299450867271,7.3884550841172976"],
    ["80.528953669541707,7.3875715810979612"],
    ["80.528714422417153,7.3867339810469588"]
  ]
]

const res = arr[0].map(e => e[0].split(',').map(el => parseFloat(el)))

console.log(res)
```