# How do I remove double quotes from a multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Q: Did you find the same question asked before?

A: Yes, here's the [link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57313736/remove-double-quotes-from-the-js-array) exactly looks like mine but the answers are not applicable because it converts the string to a number.

Q: Why do you need to remove the double quotes?

A: Because I need to follow the syntax allowed for `moment` js.

Q: Did you try removing the double quotes from the provider/backend?

A: Yes, as you can see in the Backend Code snippet below, it didn't work from what I tried *(this question accepts solutions in either javascript or PHP)*.

Q: What have you tried using JavaScript?

A: I tried this one but it didn't work as you will also see in the attachment.

```
const timeIntervalsData = [
  [
    "moment({ hour:6, minute:45 }), moment({ hour:7, minute:45 })",
  ],
  [
    "moment({ hour:10, minute:30 }), moment({ hour:11, minute:30 })",
  ],
]

let string = JSON.stringify(timeIntervalsData)
string.replace (/"/g,'')
```

[image]

---

**Moving on to the actual code**

This is where I will put the multidimensional array:

```
const timeIntervalsData = []

// the `timeIntervalsData` array will hold the 
// response of the ajax call from my backend/provider

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'call-url-of-backend',
    data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN},
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.status == true) {
            timeIntervalsData = data.time
        }
    },error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var r = jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText)
        console.log(r.message)
    }
})

let options = {
    format: 'hh:mm A',
    // here is where I load the multidimensional array
    disabledTimeIntervals: timeIntervalsData,

    // original syntax 
    // from https://getdatepicker.com/4/Options/#disabledtimeintervals 
    // and https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/object/
    disabledTimeIntervals: [
        [moment({ hour:6, minute:45 }), moment({ hour:7, minute:45 })],
        [moment({ hour:10, minute:30 }), moment({ hour:11, minute:30 })],
    ],
}

$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker(options)
```

Backend Code:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$schedules = Schedule::select('start_time', 'end_time')
    ->whereBelongsTo($user)
    ->where('weekday', 1)
    ->get()
    ->toArray();

$collection = collect($schedules)->map(function ($time) {
    return [date("g:i", strtotime($time['start_time'])), date("g:i", strtotime($time['end_time']))];
});

$data = $collection->values()->all();

$carrier = [];

foreach ($dataas $key => $a) {
  $detail1 = preg_split('/:/i', $a[0]);
  $detail2 = preg_split('/:/i', $a[1]);

  // here I try to remove " using str_replace
  array_push($carrier, array(str_replace('"', "", 'moment({ hour:'.$detail1[0].', minute:'.$detail1[1].' }), moment({ hour:'.$detail2[0].', minute:'.$detail2[1].' })')));
}

return response()->json([
    'status' => true,
    'time' => $carrier,
], 200);

// `$carrier` result
[
  [
    "moment({ hour:6, minute:45 }), moment({ hour:7, minute:45 })",
  ],
  [
    "moment({ hour:10, minute:30 }), moment({ hour:11, minute:30 })",
  ],
]
```

---

**EDIT**

This edit provides the result of testing KooiInc's code

```
const timeIntervalsData = JSON.stringify({
    moments: [
        { hour: 6, minute: 45 }, { hour: 7, minute: 45 },
        { hour: 10, minute: 30 }, { hour: 11, minute: 30 }
    ]
});

let options = {
    format: 'hh:mm A',
    disabledTimeIntervals: [
        JSON.parse(timeIntervalsData).moments.forEach( interval => moment(interval) )
    ],
}

console.log(options)
```

Console result

[image]

---

**EDIT #2**

I've edited the question to show the result of KooiInc's updated answer.

```
const timeIntervalsData = JSON.stringify( { moments: [ 
  { hour: 6, minute: 45 }, { hour: 7, minute: 45 },
  { hour: 10, minute: 30 }, { hour: 11, minute: 30 } ] 
});

JSON.parse(timeIntervalsData).moments.forEach( interval => 
  console.log(moment(interval)) );

let options = {
    format: 'hh:mm A',
    disabledTimeIntervals: [
        JSON.parse(timeIntervalsData).moments.map( interval => moment(interval) )
    ],
}

console.log(options);
```

Now I remember why I'm trying to format the `moment` in my backend code because mapping the object is combining the moment's `time intervals` into a single array like below, and because of this it completely ignores the 3rd and 4th `moment` time intervals and the 1st and 2nd-time intervals are only disabled.

Using the code above...

```
// console.log(options.disabledTimeIntervals); result
disabledTimeIntervals: [
    [M, M, M, M] // we can see here that the map combined it into a single array, the first two times are disabled but the 3rd and 4th moment is not working.
],
```

in this hardcoded moment `time intervals`, it's not combining into a single array.

```
disabledTimeIntervals: [
    [moment({ hour:6, minute:45 }), moment({ hour:7, minute:45 })],
    [moment({ hour:10, minute:30 }), moment({ hour:11, minute:30 })]
],

// console result
disabledTimeIntervals: [
    [M, M],
    [M, M]
]
```

Comment: _"Yes, here's the [link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57313736/remove-double-quotes-from-the-js-array) exactly looks like mine but the answers are not applicable because it converts the string to a number"_ - Then replace the part with the conversion. Search how to "execute" (`eval`ulate) a string that is JavaScript.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(timeIntervalsData)` - `JSON.stringify()` converts a type into a string. The content of the arrays is already a string.

Comment: why do you need to send it like this `"moment({ hour:6, minute:45 }), moment({ hour:7, minute:45 })"` ? as long as you know that you will use `moment` in the client side, you can send an array of the values, like `{"hour": 6, "minute": 45}` and in the other side, iterate over the values and instantiate it using `moment`

Comment: It makes no sense to return JavaScript code, that uses a specific library, from the back-end. Return an object with only hours and minutes and then handle the conversion on the client - with whatever library/thing you're using there.

Comment: @Andreas, I do it from the backend because I'm really a novice in frontend or javascript, I can't manipulate the response on what I wanted it to be. I hope you understand.

Comment: You then have to learn how to do it the right way ;) It really is a terrible idea to return something like `moment({ ... })` from the back-end. Especially when `moment` is _"deprecated"_ -> https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Comment: >You then have to learn how to do it the right way

I'm finding a way, that's why I posted the question thinking someone have done this before or have inputs that are not questioning again the author. If you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is always a *string* representation. You can't store function calls *as function calls* within it.

So, rethink your code and deliver another object you can use client side. Let the server deliver moments as an array of arrays, containing intervals ([begin, end]) and use `moment` client side.

Something like:

```js
// server delivers object with property
// 'moments', containing an array of arrays ([start, end])
const timeIntervalsData = JSON.stringify( { moments: [ 
    [ { hour: 6, minute: 45 }, { hour: 7, minute: 45 }, ],
    [ { hour: 10, minute: 30 }, { hour: 11, minute: 30 }, ]  
  ]
});

// based on comments
// -----------------
let options = {
    format: 'hh:mm A',
    disabledTimeIntervals: JSON.parse(timeIntervalsData)
      .moments
      .map( ([start, end]) => [ moment(start), moment(end) ] )
//    ^ mapping the individual intervals (start, end)
}

console.log(options.disabledTimeIntervals);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'll try your answer, but before that, I will update my backend code first to objects. Thank you.

Comment: I'll try putting the actual code to see if it works before updating my code, but it didn't work getting `undefined`. I updated my question to include the result.

Comment: If you want to assign the intervals to `disabl. edTimeIntervals`, you should not use `forEach`, but `Array.map`. See edited answer.

Comment: I tried and tested the code and see a difference in why it's not working when two or more objects are used.

Comment: "...when two or more objects are used" => remove `[` and `]` in the assignment

Comment: did you mean here? `disabledTimeIntervals: []` to `disabledTimeIntervals:`

Comment: Yep. That creates a nested array.

Comment: Noted, let me I'll try...

Comment: I used this one from your updated answer `disabledTimeIntervals: JSON.parse(timeIntervalsData).moments.map( interval => moment(interval) )` but still gives me this in my console `[M, M, M, M]`, supposed to be comma separated array `[M, M], [M, M]`

Comment: thank you very much for your patience. It's working now, now my job is to work on the backend to return a result like this 'server delivers object with property
// 'moments', containing an array of arrays ([start, end])'

Comment: I've managed to make it work, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74202127/20147460 it only has a difference from your given answer, take a look.