# How to format collections to object with arrays using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Every row in my schedules table has `start_time` and `end_time`.
I can get and map them by using the code below.

My question is how can I deliver an object with `moments` as an array of arrays, containing the intervals `start_time`, `end_time` of every row I get from my `schedules` table?

Below is the format I want to achieve, you can see there are two arrays inside of `moments` they are the two rows that came from my `schedules` table.

```
{
    moments: [ 
        [ { hour: 6, minute: 45 }, { hour: 7, minute: 45 }, ],
        [ { hour: 10, minute: 30 }, { hour: 11, minute: 30 }, ]  
    ]
}
```

Here are my `schedules` table and sample records.

```
+----------+------------------+----------------+-------------+
|    id    |    start_time    |    end_time    |   user_id   |
+----------+------------------+----------------+-------------+
|    1     |       6:45       |      7:45      |      1      |
|    2     |       10:30      |      11:30     |      1      |
+----------+------------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Code

```
$user = User::find(1);

$schedules = Schedule::select('start_time', 'end_time')
  ->whereBelongsTo($user)
  ->get();

$collection = $schedules->map(function ($time) {
  return [date("g:i", strtotime($time['start_time'])), date("g:i", strtotime($time['end_time']))];
});

$data = $collection->values()->all();

// result
[
  [
    "6:45",
    "7:45",
  ],
  [
    "10:30",
    "11:30",
  ],
]
```

Q: Why do I need that specific format?

A: Because I will use that on the client side's DateTimePicker to disable time intervals - https://getdatepicker.com/4/Options/#disabledtimeintervals

**Client side code**

Here I will access the formatted response from my backend by passing it inside `JSON.stringify()`.

```
const timeIntervalsData = JSON.stringify( { moments: [ 
    [ { hour: 6, minute: 45 }, { hour: 7, minute: 45 }, ],
    [ { hour: 10, minute: 30 }, { hour: 11, minute: 30 }, ]  
  ]
});

let options = {
    format: 'hh:mm A',
    disabledTimeIntervals: JSON.parse(timeIntervalsData)
      .moments
      .map( ([start, end]) => [ moment(start), moment(end) ] )
}

$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker(options)
```

Comment: Hey Tim, I understand, thank you for the heads up. EDIT: updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing my own answer to this question from SO.

in my controller method

```
$user = User::find(1);
$schedules = Schedule::select('start_time', 'end_time')
    ->whereBelongsTo($user)
    ->get();

$collection = $schedules->map(function ($time) {
    return [
        date("H:i", strtotime($time['start_time'])),
        date("H:i", strtotime($time['end_time'])),
    ];
});

return response()->json([
    'status' => true,
    'time' => $collection->all(),
], 200);
```

client side

```
<input type="text" name="time" class="datetimepicker" required>

// From AJAX response.
const time = data.time

// Format the times into moment.js instances.
const timeIntervalsData = time.map(function(schedule) {
    return [
        moment(schedule[0], 'H:mm'), // Start time
        moment(schedule[1], 'H:mm') // End time
    ]
})

let options = {
    format: 'hh:mm A',
    disabledTimeIntervals: timeIntervalsData
}

$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker(options)
```

Hope this helps anyone with the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can map over all the items in the collection and then use something like

```
$collection = collect($schedules)->map(function ($time) {
  // your logic
return [
'hour' => $time->start_time->diff($time->end_time)->format('%H'),
'minute' => $time->start_time->diff($time->end_time)->format('%I'),
],
});
```

And in your model make sure you cast them to Carbon instances, that makes it easier.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your answer correctly, but I think that is different based on the question. EDIT: not my downvote.

Comment: seems like I cannot cast a `time` only column. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators. `Call to a member function diff() on string`

Comment: That's not casting; you'd want something like `protected $dates = ['start_time', 'end_time'];`, or `protected $casts = ['start_time' => 'carbon', 'end_time' => 'carbon'];` in your `Schedule` model, something like https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting. `start_time` is a string, and `'whatever'->diff()` is invalid. If it's a `Carbon` instance, then `Carbon('whatever')->diff()` is valid 

Comment: @TimLewis this does not do what I want `[ { hour: 6, minute: 45 }, { hour: 7, minute: 45 }, ],`

Comment: That matches your expected JS array... but if you want it like `'6:45'`, or `'7:45'`, you'd do `return [$time->start_time->diff($time->end_time)->format('H:i')];`. This answer _does_ accomplish what you're expecting, based on the answer you posted, you simply needed to adjust it a bit to fit the exact format you're expecting. This answer uses Carbon, which is a DateTime library included with Laravel, where yours uses PHP's `date()` logic.

Comment: @TimLewis , I'll try to update my code to use this one (carbon).

Comment: Can't make it work, seems like `carbon` is not valid to use in `$casts`, also tried `'start_time' => 'datetime:h:i'`. Error: `Call to a member function diff() on string`

Comment: Ah; for some reason I thought `carbon` was valid in `$casts` . In the past it would have been `protected $dates = ['start_time', 'end_time'];`, but that was [deprecated in Laravel 8](https://github.com/laravel-shift/blueprint/issues/391). It suggests `protected $casts = ['start_time' => 'datetime', 'end_time' => 'datetime']`, but I don't think that uses Carbon (I can verify once I set up a L8 instance)